# How to cancel or replace a background worker that is busy doing a SQL call?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

So my background worker starts off and calls the database for data (depending on how much data there is it can take a few extra seconds than normal). If during this data call the overall context changes for example say I'm currently loading a full list of football players and this load takes 10 seconds to complete but now I've clicked on the UI to only show staff now then the background worker "breaks" and says it's busy.

For now I've been stopping the user from changing the context of the UI until it has completed the SQL load which is a fix but I feel there should be something better to do.

I've looked into the cancelling of a background worker but this again is slightly useless because the worker is still busy running the SQL for it to cancel.

I've also tried to create a new instance of the worker and this works but it actually just creates another thread for the new worker to run on. For example the worker starts loading the list of players, user changes the context to staff, staff list loads and then the players list loads which overwrites the staff list.

```
if (loader.IsBusy)
{
    loader = new BackgroundWorker();
    loader.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    loader.DoWork += CompanyIDChanged;
    loader.ProgressChanged += Loader_ProgressChanged;
    loader.RunWorkerCompleted += Loader_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

loader.RunWorkerAsync();
```

That's how I'm currently "replacing" the worker.

The result I would like to happen is the following.

1. The worker starts loading the list of players
2. The UI is changed so that they want staff now
3. The worker is essentially disposed of in whatever state it's in
4. The worker then runs again with the new context

Is the background worker even suitable for this scenario? Is there something better to use? Or am I looking at this wrong and need to rethink what I'm doing?

Comment: Remove the event handlers from the old object before you create a new one. Then you can just let it run and ignore its results.

Comment: You need a semiphore like waitone so you do not start a 2nd backgroundworker until first is completed.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You would have to handle threads yourself by using [`Task.Run()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_System_Threading_CancellationToken_). There is an overload that takes a [`CancellationToken`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8#examples). This token allows to gracefully cancel the `Task`. After it is cancelled you just start a new `Task` using `TAsk.Run()` again. The `BackgroundWorker` doesn't offer cancellation.

Comment: This way you don't need any locking like the suggested `Semaphore`. Just store a reference to the current `CancellationToken` (which is a `IDisposable`). When the user switches to another page you use this reference to cancel the running task(s). After that you need to dispose the `CancellationToken`, since it can't be reused once cancelled.. Then create a new one and start the new `Task`.

Comment: [Microsoft Docs: How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)

Comment: Also to improve or reduce waiting time. You should store the current progrees onm cancellation. So that when the user comees back tothe page you can continue from where you left.

Comment: I have to add that  [`BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync?view=netframework-4.8) also allows cancellation. But I found `Task` to be more convenient to use. The produced code also looks cleaner to me.